# How can i read md5 from this file

Tags: c#

Ok so first, i have it writing to the file..

```
string line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7, line8, line9, line10;
// step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
byte[] inputBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password);
byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

// step 2, convert byte array to hex string
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
}
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
{
    sw.WriteLine(Username);
    sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Then. how can i make it so it can be read from the file?
As normal text. Not the encrypted form

Comment: md5 is an unreversable hash, that's the whole point. It's impossible to get it as "normal text".

Comment: So what would be a good way to encrypt a password then decrypt it or encrypt a file or something.. i need a way to store the user and pass but encrypt the pass.. or atleast the file..

Comment: You shouldn't decrypt passwords. You should generate a hash and store that like you're doing. When the user logs in they will supply their password which you then hash again and compare the hashes.

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful guide here: [NET-Encryption-Simplified](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10154/NET-Encryption-Simplified)